# Basic algorithm inquiry

Tags: algorithm

I have a simple slideShow with a next and previous button.  Here are my functions:

```
function nextSlide(){
    _currentSlide++;
    _nextSlide = _currentSlide % _slides.length;
}

function prevSlide(){
    if(_currentSlide == 0) _currentSlide = _slides.length;
    _currentSlide--;
    _prevSlide = _currentSlide % _slides.length;
}
```

While this works, I'm wondering (within my prevSlide function) if I can avoid using the "if conditional" altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
function prevSlide(){
    _currentSlide = (_currentSlide + _slides.length - 1) % _slides.length;
    _prevSlide = _currentSlide;
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  And the nextSlide can be converted to this as well... _currentSlide = (_currentSlide + 1) % _slides.length;